# How to navigate from one stack or module to another stack or module

Tags: react-redux, react-router, react-native, react-native-navigation

Appnavigation.js

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import Splash from "./components/splace";
import Login from "./components/login";
import Main from "./components/Main";

const SplashStack = createStackNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: Splash, navigationOptions: { header: null } }
})

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login, navigationOptions: { header: null } }
})

const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: Main, navigationOptions: { header: null } }
});

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  // Splash: SplashStack,
  Login: LoginStack,
  Main: MainStack

})
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Whenever the login process is done then it will navigate to "Main Screen" where the module selection process will be done and it will move in that particular directory's index file where I have another stack of screens.

Main.js

```
class Main extends Component {
  Module = null;
  componentWillMount() {

    switch (this.props.user.userTypeName) {
      case "Student": {
        Module = require("./student").default;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <Module />;
  }
}
```

Student Module or directory's "index.js"

```
const App = createStackNavigator(

  {
    Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard},
    Profile: { screen: Profile },
  },
);

export default createAppContainer(App);
```

I want to move from Student Dashboard or profile screen to the login screen when I clicked on the logout button which I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Have you tried `this.props.navigation('Login')` onpress logout button?

Comment: yup already try that

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a `console.log(props)` ? 
Then you can see how to call navigation.

You can try `this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');`
instead of `this.props.navigation('Login');`

When you do a console.log you will possibly get an 'navigation' object wich has an 'navigate' inside it.

Comment: i try both of them but it will not navigate from one screen to another.